# Porquê ng-repeat nao funciona em json php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho um app móvel em que faço um `ng-repeat` para listar uma galeria de fotos que bem através de um `JSON` php o que acontece e que acho que tenho todo bem mas não me lista nenhuma imagem já testei a `query sql` directamente no `sql` e não me da nenhum erro lista bem.

**Controller**

```
.controller('VerFotosEstabelecimento', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_ver_fotos_estabelecimento.php?slug="+$stateParams.EstabelecimentoSlug).success(function (data) {
        $scope.ver_fotos_estabelecimento = data;
    });
})
```

**HTML onde listo as fotos**

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <h2 style="margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">Fotos</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" ng-repeat="fotos in ver_fotos_estabelecimento"> 
                    <img ng-src="https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/fotos/{{fotos.id_anexo}}.{{fotos.tipo}}" />
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div style="float: left;" ng-click="fotos()" ng-controller="ModalFotos" class="caixa_limite">+'.$fotos_maior_valida.'</div>
            <div style="float: left; margin:0px 0px 20px 5px;" class="caixa_limite"><i style="font-size: xx-large;" class="ion-camera"></i></div>  
        </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Content-type: application/json");

require_once("../funcoes/funcoes.php");


$result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos
                            INNER JOIN estabelecimentos_anexos ON estabelecimentos_anexos.id_mae = estabelecimentos.id
                            WHERE estabelecimentos.slug = :slug  AND estabelecimentos_anexos.seccao = :seccao LIMIT 9");

$result->bindValue(':slug', $_GET['slug'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':seccao', 'fotos', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Da uma olhada no formato que o teu json está vindo. Pode ocorrer do json estar em formato texto. Por isso ele não tem o comportamento esperado. Nesse caso terá que dar um eval quando receber os valores da chamada ajax

Comment: Outra coisa, no teu fonte não vi a definição do controller no HTML nem do App. Acredito que possam estar no código mais acima. Porém pergunto só pra confirmar

Comment: Está no app configurado

Comment: E sobre o tipo retornado, consegue verificar se é um texto ou json?

Comment: Vou verificar como esta a vir

Comment: Está vindo em formato texto

Comment: Faça o seguinte então. $scope.ver_fotos_estabelecimento = eval(data);

Comment: Fiz isso mas nao resolveu

Comment: de um console.log( $scope.ver_fotos_estabelecimento = eval(data))  veja o que aparece no console do browser

Comment: Não aparece nada na console

Comment: já consegui resolver era um conflito com o ng-controller